# Move every picture taken outside of interval to a subfolder

Tags: macos, terminal, exiftool

I am trying to figure out a solution for moving every picture taken outside of a interval (let's say every 2 seconds) into a new subfolder.

Example:
I have 5 pictures with the following meta info:

pic1 - 10:05.02
pic2 - 10:05.03
pic3 - 10:05.04
pic4 - 10:05.06
pic5 - 10:05.07

What I want to achieve is to move pic2 and pic5 to a new subfolder. I was wondering if that would be possible using ExifTool but then again I have no idea how to use that one. The files are already named using the metadata (DD.MM.YYYY_HH:MM:SS)

Does anyone has any ideas? Really appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Points to clarify: 1) Your filenames contain a colon?  It's my understanding that a filename cannot contain a colon on a Mac.  2) You want to move only only pics 2 and 5, but not pic 1?   -  You might want to bring this over to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/), as it will probably take more than a few questions to work out the details.

Comment: @StarGeek 1) My mistake its a regular dot! 
2) hmm...yes I figured the best Idea would be to define that all files with the last number being either 2,4,6,8 or 0 would not be moved and every other file would be moved...

3) Oh well I did not know they had a forum, thanks so much I will try that!!

Comment: Ah, I missed the every 2 second part.  I was thinking that you meant images before 10:05.03 and after 10:05.06, which would be easy.

Comment: @starGeek no, but I figured just sorting based on the last number of the filename should probably also be quite easy to accomplish right?

Comment: Yeah, as long as all the filenames were the same pattern, you could use something like: `exiftool -fast3 -if '$Filename!~m/_\d\d\.\d\d\.\d[02468]/' -directory=/path/to/odd_numbers/`  That uses a regex match to the time portion of the filename, checking for an even number as the last digit and the `!~` indicates that it is a NOT operation. The [`-fast3` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#fast-NUM) is used to avoid reading the embedded metadata to speed things up since only the system filename is looked at.